# How can I format a date within a longer string in a Jinja template with flask_babel?

Tags: python, jinja2, python-babel, flask-babel

Within a jinja template, I have the following string

```
# English
<p>by John Smith on <time pubdate="pubdate" datetime="2019-01-30T20:54:55">January 30, 2019</time></p>

# German
<p>am <time pubdate="pubdate" datetime="2019-01-30T20:54:55">30. Januar 2019</time> von John Smith veröffentlicht</p>
```

### 1st try

Having the date formatted / localized in the backend:

```
# In the routes.py:
pubdate = '<time pubdate="pubdate" datetime="{date_iso}">{date_localized}</time>' \
    .format(date_iso=pubdate.isoformat(),
            date_localized=flask_babel.dates.format_date(pubdate))

# In the jinja template:
<p>{{_('by %(author)s on %(pubdate)s', author=author, pubdate=pubdate)}}</p>
```

But then I have to care about HTML outside of a Jinja template which I would like to avoid.

What I would like to achieve:

1. **✓** Have semantic tags for time.
2. **✗** Don't have HTML within Python files: Backend developers should not have to deal with HTML
3. **✓** Don't have HTML within `pot` files: Translators should not have to deal with HTML

### 2nd try

I tried

```
<p>{{_('by %(author)s on %(pubdate)s',
       author=author,
       pubdate='<time pubdate="pubdate" datetime="{pubdate}">{pubdate}</time>'.format(pubdate=pubdate))}}</p>
```

This has multiple problems

1. The `<time>` tag gets escaped - and it would not be safe to use the `safe` jinja filter
2. I don't know how to format `pubdate` here, because `babel.dates.format_datetime` is not known here

### 3rd try

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    print(_('Hello World!'))
    flash(_('Hello World!'))
    pubdate = datetime.datetime.now()
    return render_template("main.html",
                           pubdate=pubdate,
                           author='John Smith',
                           date_localized=flask_babel.dates.format_date(pubdate))
```

main.html:

```
<p>{{_('by %(author)s on %(pubdate)s', author=author, pubdate='<time pubdate="pubdate" datetime="{pubdate}">{date_localized}</time>'.format(pubdate=pubdate, date_localized=date_localized))}}</p>
```

displayed as:

```
by John Smith on <time pubdate="pubdate" datetime="2019-08-11 18:26:54.428453">11.08.2019</time>
```

So the problem is that the tag gets escaped. But I probably shouldn't use `safe` as `<` or `>` could be within the translation.

See [Github](https://github.com/MartinThoma/algorithms/tree/master/Python/flask/l10n) for a minimal example.

Comment: Why aren't you just formatting the date at the backend before rendering the template?

Comment: @roganjosh I've added this as "3rd try". I would have hoped that there is a solution where I don't have to pass the same information in multiple formats.

Comment: The alternative being to pass the same format once and get the template parser to fix the format twice? It's only offloading work elsewhere. _Somewhere_ this has to be processed, why in the template language?